# Use jquery-steps with FormGroup in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, jquery-steps

Please see the following examples. I have loaded `jquery` and `jquery-steps` into the project already and it is working. However after rendering the view, changing the data in the input boxes doesn't update the values in the form group `mainForm`. I believe the reason is that `jquery-steps` dynamically removed and reconstructed the html for the form, and so the form group doesn't link to the DOMs anymore.

Is there any way to re-bind FormGroup `mainForm` to the DOMs after `jquery-steps` reconstructed the html?

I read about `ComponentResolver` and `ViewContainerRef`, is it where it should use those? Could you give me an example how to use those in this situation?

Thank you!

```html
<pre>{{ mainForm.value | json }}</pre>

<form [formGroup]="mainForm" id="mainForm" action="#">
    <h1>Account</h1>
    <div>
        <label for="userName">User name *</label>
        <input formControlName="userName" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="password">Password *</label>
        <input formControlName="password" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="confirm">Confirm Password *</label>
        <input formControlName="confirm" type="text" class="required">
        <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
    </div>
    <h1>Finish</h1>
    < div>
        <input formControlName="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> 
        <label for="acceptTerms">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
import {Component, AfterContentInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'main-view.template.html'
})
export class MainViewComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    private mainForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            userName: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
            confirm: ['', Validators.required],
            acceptTerms: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        $("#mainForm").steps();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason why that is not working is that jquery-steps plugin removes your html markup.

Using jquery in angular2 is bad idea but if you want to get it working i can offer you slightly modify the library

**jquery.steps.js**

```
function render(wizard, options, state) {
+    var contentWrapper = $('<{0} class=\"{1}\"></{0}>'.format(options.contentContainerTag, "content " + options.clearFixCssClass));
+    contentWrapper.append(wizard.children());
    // Create a content wrapper and copy HTML from the intial wizard structure
    var wrapperTemplate = "<{0} class=\"{1}\">{2}</{0}>",
        orientation = getValidEnumValue(stepsOrientation, options.stepsOrientation),
        verticalCssClass = (orientation === stepsOrientation.vertical) ? " vertical" : "",
-       //contentWrapper = $(wrapperTemplate.format(options.contentContainerTag, "content " + options.clearFixCssClass, wizard.html())),
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/fZyqsPeWhEPpUamIPeYW?p=preview)**

Comment: hi yurzui.. I need to disable continue button until I meet the exact condition..ex: without filling username user can not allow to continue(disable button).In angular context how can I do this? thanks