# angular 2 click event not working when render the component using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to add click event to the button inside angular 2 component:

.html file

```
<td><button (click)="addProduct()" #add>Add</button></td>
```

and .ts file :

```
 addProduct()
 {
    console.log("new product added");
 }
```

but this component rendered inside a jquery:

```
$("#order").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        autoFocus: true,

      });
```

where order:

```
<div id="order">
    <app-set-order></app-set-order> //component that contains the button 
</div>
```

why this is not works as expected?

Comment: are you using button inside *ngfor?

Comment: No the button is in the last row in the table and other rows generated using *ngfor but the button is not inside *ngfor

Comment: its should work. Try to create plunker.

Comment: What is the error you get if any?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582639/use-jquery-steps-with-formgroup-in-angular2

Comment: @yurzui Thank you for helping that's works perfectly